# $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin x_n}{x_n}$ if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n =0$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to easily prove that 
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin x_n}{x_n}=1,$$ 
if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n =0$?

I proved it using inequality 
$$ 1-\frac{x^2}{2}<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$$
therefore,
$$1\xleftarrow[\text{$x_n \to 0$}]{}1-\frac{x_n^2}{2}<\frac{\sin x_n}{x_n}<1 \longrightarrow 1$$

Comment: If you know L'hospital's rule, this is a very easy example. If else, squeeze theorem is your best bet.

Comment: Welcome, since $\sin x$ has a convergent Taylor series for all real nubmer, thus also near $0$, do the substitution, after simplify and evaluate the limit in your sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help! I've came up with the proper estimate, which could be obtained without 'magic logic circles':
$$\sin x < x < \tan x$$
$$\frac{1}{\sin x} > \frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{\tan x}$$
$$1\leftarrow1=\frac{\sin x_n}{\sin x_n} > \frac{\sin x_n}{x_n} > \frac{\sin x_n}{\tan x_n} = \cos x_n \xrightarrow[\text{$x_n \to 0$}]{} 1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim \limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0}=(\sin x)'|_{x=0}=\cos 0=1.
$$

Comment: It seems like a valid proof... except for the fact that proving or establishing the derivative of the sine function requires using this limit. That's why this special limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ **has to be established independently, without using derivatives** -- because otherwise we fall into a logical vicious circle of two "proofs" using each other.

Comment: @zipirovich Indeed, exactly **the same** with what the OP uses to bound it. You decide which one is more elementary, and in case you think a new answer is a must you should go ahead. Otherwise, that's it.

Comment: I agree! With some minor variations, I know only one proof of this limit. It can found in pretty much any Calculus textbook. It requires looking at some triangles and arcs on the unit circle followed by an application of the Squeeze / Pinching Theorem. One such proof can be found here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofTrigDeriv.aspx. There are shorter ways to present it, but at the moment I can't remember where to find them online.

Comment: @zipirovich I had a look and it is quite nice. :) But we all know that the definition goes through power series, in which case it is an immediate consequence of the fact that analytic functions are continuous. Otherwise it boils down to what each of us is allowed to use, the OP should perhaps clarify this point.

Comment: Once again, I completely agree! You're hard to argue with. :-)

Comment: @Jonas It's not allowed to use derivatives and other calculus beyond limits of sequences. This problem actually accured while solving another problem:  find the $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ of function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ $$f(x)=\left( \frac{\sin^2 \sqrt{x}}{x}, x\left[ \frac{1}{x} \right] \right)$$. The answer is $(1,1)$ and I'm trying to prove it using Heine definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is good. Alternatively, you can use the fact that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$
And also use the following fact: if $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) = a$ and $x_n\to c$, then $f(x_n)\to a$.

Comment: No, you can't. Same problem as I described in the comment to the other answer: L\H\^{o}pital's Rule requires knowing the derivative of the sine function, which in turn requires using this limit, which requires knowing the derivative, which requires this limit...

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Yes, if the OP's question is about how it applies to a sequence, then your answer now addressed it very well!